# CXF call REST service with JSON

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, cxf

I've a little issue, this because my experience with REST and JSON is not so good!

However i've this service

```
 @Path("/baseService")
 @Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON, MediaType.TEXT_XML})
 @Consumes({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,       MediaType.TEXT_XML,MediaType.APPLICATION_XML})
 public interface BaseService {

 @POST
 @Path("/registration")
 @Transactional
 public UserTO register(@RequestBody UserTO userto);
```

I would like to send a json from the clent to test the service

if I call him without json, everything works well:

```
 resp=client.post(userTO);
```

But i don't know how to call it sending and json (and let spring jackson converting it for you from json to UserTO object) Reading online some solutions i try:

```
client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).type(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).query("mail", "test").query("name", "test").query("psw", "test").query("role", "cassa").query("surname", "fsddsf").query("userName", "fsdfs").post(UserTO.class);
```

or

```
 resp=client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(inputJsonObj);
```

how can I do this? please help!

Answer (score 1):

You can pass your json as jsonobject (`jsonObject.toString()`) to output stream created for the endpoint of your service.

```
URL url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/yourapp/baseService/registration");
URLConnection connection = url.openConnection();
connection.setDoOutput(true);
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
connection.setConnectTimeout(5000);
connection.setReadTimeout(5000);
OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(connection.getOutputStream());
out.write(jsonObject.toString());
out.close();

BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
```

Comment: `new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()` loses the character set. With JSON it should always be UTF-8, so `new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF-8)` is better

Comment: @artbristol .. thanks, updated the answer as per the suggestion.

Comment: It is `UTF_8` and not `UTF-8` as far as I am concerned.

Answer (score 1):

In case you just want to test your application then in that case you can use postman plugin for chrome.

Jakson have ObjectMapper class which will help you to convert the java obj to/from pojo.

Answer (score 0):

Resolved in this way, changing

```
 resp=client.accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON).post(inputJsonObj);
```

with:

```
 users = client.post(inputJsonObj, UserTO.class);
```

Passing the JSON object and the class i want to convert it to!